# STL container for BIG (>13MB) structure

Tags: c++, stl, stack-overflow

I have currently a VERY BIG structure >13MB (and it HAS to remain like that, because I can't have pointer). My problem is how to store it into a class.

If it is part of the class, I get stackoverflow. If I use pointers the problem is solved, until I need to start copying the classes.... then the hell starts. (since the class has a lot of members).

I tryed with STL vector and array, but I still get the stackoverflow. Is any STL container that does not put the structure in the stack but it directly allocates the memory?

This way I can have everything properly done.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Example code:

```
//HEADER
#include <vector>
struct BigStruct { //This is untouchable or divisible into an array of arrays
    char a[1000];
    int b[1000][1000];
    long c[1000000];
    // etc...
};

class Foo
{
    std::vector<BigStruct> a; //It has to be here since is related to this instance of the class

public:
    Foo();
    //All the other funcs and method
    // ...

    //All the other variables are from STL
    // ...
};

//CPP
Foo::Foo(){
 a.resize(1);
}
```

Comment: std::vector allocates on the heap, you shouldn't be getting a stackoverflow with it.

Comment: Remember that the stack is generally only a couple of MB, so if you declare it as a local variable then you will most certainly get stack overflow.

Comment: if it's 15mb, and you're using it as normal class that you can just use as a local variable on the stack, and keep copying it from one place to another... you have a real design issue.

Comment: You are probably creating a temporary instance of this structure on the stack which is causing the overflow. Please provide code of how you insert to vector.

Comment: Also, is it like an array of at least this size? Or is each object over this size? The solutions might differ quote a lot depending on that. If the latter, do you store all of the data inside the object (e.g. in an array) or do you just have a pointer to the heap?

Comment: It is just one big structure, for each class. The class and the structure are different things, but the class has that structure inside.
I would like to use a STL container to hold this structure inside the class and handle automatically the copy operation.
I can use a pointer, but in that case, I have to handle all the class copy operation/destruction/etc.

Comment: What about `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`? You don't need to have copy behavior for that .

Comment: maybe unique_ptr is what I need. But I can't make it compile. Since it sais that 'cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Comment: How can we help without seeing the code?

Answer (score 0):

I am just answering my own question. When calling `resize()` std::vector creates a element of type BigStruct in the stack and then copies it the number of times specified.

This behaviour can be avoided by creating the element in the vector like this:

```
Foo::Foo(){
 BigStruct * temp = new BigStruct;
 a.clear();
 a.push_back(*temp); //Element is reserved and copied directly from temp.
 delete temp;
}
```

This completely solves the stack issue, and allows portability(copy, move destroy) of the parent class.

Comment: And leaks 13MB of memory each time. Heap memory, though, so your stack issue is indeed solved.

Comment: Oh, yes I need the delete temp at the end. Sry.

Comment: I would have used a smart pointer, there's still a leak but only if   `.push_back` throws.